# does sony smarteyeglass support the UI platform Unity?

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I'm planning to develop an app for Sony SmartEyeglass via Unity, however, I'm not sure if that's possible. Is it possible, or do I have to use Android Studio unconditionally?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly use Unity3D for developing SmartEyeglass applications.

You need to use Android Studio with SmartEyeglass SDK.